# How to intercept/handle back button in landscape with master/detail views

Tags: navigation, swiftui

This question started out as a request for suggestions on how to clear or redraw the detail view when the original master view re-appears, but in creating the example, I discovered that without any @State variables, that original view is being force refreshed far more than necessary and would like to understand why and how to do what I need.

```
import SwiftUI

var ctr = 0


struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView())
            {
                Text("Left Pane")
                .padding()
                    .onAppear()
                    {
                        ctr = ctr+1
                        print("Appear \(ctr)")
                    }
            }.isDetailLink(false)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView())
        {
            Text("Selector View")
                .padding()
                .onAppear()
                {
                    print("Selector Appears")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        Text("Third View - Detail")
    }
}
```

The console displays the following when the links are clicked in sequence then the back button eventually reveals the original master view.  My goal is to change the detail view to blank when I get there, but I can't see a way to do that and don't see why there are so many refreshes of each view.

```
Appear 1
Appear 2
Appear 3
Appear 4
Appear 5
Selector Appears
Selector Appears
Selector Appears
Selector Appears
Selector Appears
Appear 6
Appear 7
Appear 8
Appear 9
Appear 10
```

Put another way, my original question was how to intercept or handle the back button?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of possible approach - the idea is to reset details view explicitly because in SwiftUI we cannot just set some view to `blank` - we need to replace it with something.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14 (so some adapting for SwiftUI 1.0 might be needed)

[image: demo]

```
class DetailsState: ObservableObject { // view model to manage details
    @Published var reset = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var state = DetailsState()

    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()
                .onAppear()
                {
                    self.state.reset = true        // << should be here !!
                }
            )
            {
                Text("Left Pane")
                .padding()
            }.isDetailLink(false)
        }
        .environmentObject(state)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var state: DetailsState

    @State private var showDetails = false
    var body: some View
    {
        Button("Selector View") {
            state.reset = false      // << drop on activation
            showDetails = true       // << activate details
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            NavigationLink(destination: ThirdView(), isActive: $showDetails)
                { EmptyView() }
        )
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View     // managed container for selected views
{
    @EnvironmentObject var state: DetailsState

    var body: some View
    {
        if !state.reset {    // << show when allowed
            Text("Third View - Detail")  // << selected view here 
        }
    }
}
```